# How to generate an email with Powershell containing unknown table sizes with office-specific color schemes?

Tags: powershell, html-table, colors, office365, html-email

Dear fellow programmers,

I have tried my best to find the solution to this, but I finally decided to create a stackoverflow account and ask for help.

**What I am trying to do:**
1. Get data input from multiple sources.
2. Put that data into tables and format them as "Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5".
3. Output those tables in an email.

**What problem I am facing:**
- Since the number of columns and rows vary each time I would like to generate the email, it seems impossible to get the "Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5" to be applied to all tables and still be output as an email.

**What I have done so far:**
1. I tried to apply css as a whole to the tables, which would work, if I knew all columns and rows up front, which unfortunately I don't. I was not able to implement the TR html tags but only TH and TD.
2. I also tried to apply css to every html fragment (= table) using the -CSSUri parameter, but that does not seem to be allowed in combination with the fragment parameter.

**CODE**
The below code is what a sample result would look like, but instead of simple html css applied at the beginning, "Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5" should be applied to all tables.
Copy and paste the below code snippets in order into the Powershell IDE and run them as a whole. An email will come up. Instead of the generic blue, the "Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5" should be applied to all tables.

**Applying a generic style to all tables (should be "Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5" instead):**

```
function table_style {

$style = "<head><style>BODY{font-size: 12pt;}";
$style += "TABLE{border: 3px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; overflow-x:auto;}";
$style += "TH{border: 2px solid black; background: #4472C4; padding: 4px; }";
$style += "TD{border: 2px solid black; padding: 7px; }";
$style += "</style></head>";
return $style;

}
```

**Creating the first table (will pull data from API):**

```
function Table1_creation {
   $Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

   $col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table1_Column1,([string]);
   $col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table1_Column2,([string]);
   $col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table1_Column3,([string]);
   $Table.columns.add($col1);
   $Table.columns.add($col2);
   $Table.columns.add($col3);

   $Tablerows = "Table1_Column1_Row2","Table1_Column1_Row3","Table1_Column1_Row4","Table1_Column1_Row5","Table1_Column1_Row6";

   foreach ($Row in $Tablerows) {
   $row = $Row;
   $Table.rows.add($row) | Out-Null;
   }


   return $Table | Select Table1_Column1, Table1_Column2, Table1_Column3 | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment ;
}
```

**Creating the second table (will pull data from API):**

```
function Table2_creation {
   $Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

   $col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table2_Column1,([string]);
   $col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Tabl2_Column2,([string]);
   $Table.columns.add($col1);
   $Table.columns.add($col2);

   $Tablerows = "Table2_Column1_Row2","Table2_Column1_Row3","Table2_Column1_Row4";

   foreach ($Row in $Tablerows) {
   $row = $Row;
   $Table.rows.add($row) | Out-Null;
   }


   return $Table | Select Table2_Column1, Tabl2_Column2 | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment;
}
```

**Creating the third table (will pull data from API):**

```
function Table3_creation {
   $Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

   $col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column1,([string]);
   $col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column2,([string]);
   $col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column3,([string]);
   $col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column4,([string]);
   $col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column5,([string]);
   $col6 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column6,([string]);
   $Table.columns.add($col1);
   $Table.columns.add($col2);
   $Table.columns.add($col3);
   $Table.columns.add($col4);
   $Table.columns.add($col5);
   $Table.columns.add($col6);

   $Tablerows = "Table3_Column1_Row2","Table3_Column1_Row3";

   foreach ($Row in $Tablerows) {
   $row = $Row;
   $Table.rows.add($row) | Out-Null;
   }


   return $Table | Select Table3_Column1, Table3_Column2, Table3_Column3, Table3_Column4, Table3_Column5, Table3_Column6 | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment;
}
```

**Creating xth table with unknown columns and rows with data from API:**
    `#Create tables`

**Generating all tables and adding headings:**

```
function generate_Table1 {
$html = insert_heading "THIS IS TABLE 1";
$html += Table1_creation;
return $html;
}

function generate_Table2 {
$html = insert_heading "THIS IS TABLE 2";
$html += Table2_creation;
return $html;
}

function generate_Table3 {
$html = insert_heading "THIS IS TABLE 3";
$html += Table3_creation;
return $html;
}
```

**Generating the email:**

```
function generate_Email { 
$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0);
$emailHTML = $(table_style);

$emailHTML += if (!$tables) {
    generate_Table1;
    generate_Table2;
    generate_Table3;
} else {
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error...";
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Generating Email...";
$mail.HTMLBody = "$emailHTML";

$inspector = $mail.GetInspector;
$inspector.Display();
}

generate_Email;
```

Comment: You seem to have left out function `insert_heading`. Why is the whole thing not wrapped in `<html>...</html>`? A `<style>` definition should go in the `<head>..</head>` section as far as I know and the contents should be inside `<body>..</body>`.

Comment: Also, because the style you want needs a lot more styles defined than what you have (i.e. rows are zebra colored, column 1 has black background and white font etc.) this means you need to add inline styling on the table elements. (inline vs. class because Outlook is not the best html renderer..). `ConvertTo-Html -Fragment` will not do that for you. P.S. in PowerShell you don't need every line to have a trailing semi-colon `;`. Have you considered building the HTML in a StringBuilder instead of constantly concatenating strings?

Comment: Thank you, Theo, for the insanely fast reply! As you could see with the semi-colon at the end of each line, I am not an expert in PS, nor HTML. I will look into the StringBuilder for building the html. Thank you for the clear answer and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you need to do a lot more styling to mimic the "Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5" table styling from Word.
Because Outlook does not handle the rendering of HTML like a modern browser can, the code requires quite a number of inline style definitions.

Since `ConvertTo-Html -Fragment` cannot do that you need to manually build the HTML tables.

The code below does that using in function `ConvertTo-HtmlTable`.
It expects as parameter either a `System.Data.DataTable` object or an array of PSCustomObjects.

```
# needed for [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode()
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

function ConvertTo-HtmlTable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [object]$Table
    )
    if ($Table -is [System.Data.DataTable]) {
        # convert to array of PSCustomObjects
        $Table = $Table | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors
    }

    # manually build the HTML table
    $tdFirst = '<td style="background: black; color: white; font-weight: bold;">'
    $tdOdd   = '<td style="background: #999999;">'
    $tdEven  = '<td style="background: #CCCCCC;">'

    # add the headers row
    $headers = @($Table[0].PSObject.Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name)
    $tbl = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
    [void]$tbl.Append('<table><thead><tr>')
    foreach ($col in $headers) {
        [void]$tbl.Append("<th>$col</th>")
    }
    [void]$tbl.Append('</tr></thead><tbody>')
    # next add the data rows
    $row = 0
    $Table | ForEach-Object {
        [void]$tbl.AppendLine('<tr>')
        for ($col = 0; $col -lt $headers.Count; $col++) {
            [string]$val =$_.$($headers[$col])
            $td = if ($col -eq 0) { $tdFirst } elseif ($row -band 1) { $tdOdd } else { $tdEven }
            [void]$tbl.Append($td)
            $data = if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($val)) { '&nbsp;' } else { [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($val) }
            [void]$tbl.AppendLine("$data</td>")
        }
        [void]$tbl.AppendLine('</tr>')
        $row++
    }
    [void]$tbl.Append('</tbody></table>')

    return $tbl.ToString()
}
```

Now that we have this function in place, you then use it in your `TableX_creation` functions like this:

```
function Table1_creation {
    $Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

    $col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table1_Column1,([string])
    $col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table1_Column2,([string])
    $col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table1_Column3,([string])
    $Table.columns.add($col1)
    $Table.columns.add($col2)
    $Table.columns.add($col3)

    $Tablerows = "Table1_Column1_Row2","Table1_Column1_Row3","Table1_Column1_Row4","Table1_Column1_Row5","Table1_Column1_Row6"

    foreach ($row in $Tablerows) {
        $Table.Rows.Add($row) | Out-Null
    }

    $result = ConvertTo-HtmlTable $Table
    $Table.Dispose()

    return $result
}

function Table2_creation {
    $Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

    $col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table2_Column1,([string])
    $col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Tabl2_Column2,([string])
    $Table.columns.add($col1)
    $Table.columns.add($col2)

    $Tablerows = "Table2_Column1_Row2","Table2_Column1_Row3","Table2_Column1_Row4"

    foreach ($Row in $Tablerows) {
        $Table.Rows.Add($row) | Out-Null
    }

    $result = ConvertTo-HtmlTable $Table
    $Table.Dispose()

    return $result
}

function Table3_creation {
    $Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

    $col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column1,([string])
    $col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column2,([string])
    $col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column3,([string])
    $col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column4,([string])
    $col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column5,([string])
    $col6 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn Table3_Column6,([string])
    $Table.columns.add($col1)
    $Table.columns.add($col2)
    $Table.columns.add($col3)
    $Table.columns.add($col4)
    $Table.columns.add($col5)
    $Table.columns.add($col6)

    $Tablerows = "Table3_Column1_Row2","Table3_Column1_Row3"
    foreach ($Row in $Tablerows) {
        $Table.Rows.Add($row) | Out-Null
    }

    $result = ConvertTo-HtmlTable $Table
    $Table.Dispose()

    return $result
}
```

Next, I did a function to put all these HTML fragments together:

```
function Generate_Html { 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Generating Email Body..."

    # main style settings mimicing "Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5"
    $style = @'
<head>
    <style>
    BODY  { font-size: 12pt; font-family: calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
    TABLE { font-size: 11pt; font-family: calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            border: 0.5px solid white; border-collapse: collapse; overflow-x:auto; color: white; width: auto; }
    TH    { border: none;background: black; padding: 0 8px 0 8px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; }
    TD    { border: 0.5px solid white; padding: 0 8px 0 8px; color: black; text-align: left; }
    </style>
</head>
'@

    $sb = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
    [void]$sb.AppendLine("<html>")
    [void]$sb.AppendLine($style)
    [void]$sb.AppendLine("<body>")
    if (!$tables) {
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('<h3>THIS IS TABLE 1</h3>')
        [void]$sb.AppendLine((Table1_creation))
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('<h3>THIS IS TABLE 2</h3>')
        [void]$sb.AppendLine((Table2_creation))
        [void]$sb.AppendLine('<h3>THIS IS TABLE 3</h3>')
        [void]$sb.AppendLine((Table3_creation))
    } 
    else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error...";
    }
    [void]$sb.AppendLine("</body></html>")

    return $sb.ToString()
}
```

So at the end you do your Outlook stuff like this:

```
# I'm guessing you create your `$Outlook` variable sort of like below
if(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK")).length -gt 0){
    $Outlook = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")
}
else {
    $Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
}

$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$mail.HTMLBody = Generate_Html
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

The final outcome should then look like

[image: HTML tables]

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to convert html to XmlDocument and then add style attributes.
By using XPath you can efficiently give it style.

```bsh
filter Add-InlineStyle {
    $doc = [xml]$_

    # body
    $doc.SelectNodes("//body").SetAttribute("style", "font-size: 12pt")
    # tables
    $doc.SelectNodes("//table").SetAttribute("style", "font-size: 11pt; border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; overflow-x: auto")
    # column headers
    $doc.SelectNodes("//th").SetAttribute("style", "border: 0.5px solid white; text-align: center; padding: 0px 5px; font-weight: bold; color: white; background: black")
    # row headers
    $doc.SelectNodes("//td[1]").SetAttribute("style", "border: 0.5px solid white; text-align: center; padding: 0px 5px; font-weight: bold; color: white; background: black")
    # even rows
    $doc.SelectNodes("//tr[position() mod 2 = 0]/td[position() != 1]").SetAttribute("style", "border: 0.5px solid white; text-align: right; padding: 0px 5px; background: #CCCCCC")
    # odd rows
    $doc.SelectNodes("//tr[position() mod 2 = 1]/td[position() != 1]").SetAttribute("style", "border: 0.5px solid white; text-align: right; padding: 0px 5px; background: #999999")

    $doc.OuterXml;
}
```

The usage is below.

```bsh
$data1 = @"
Table1,Column1,Column2
Row1,1,2
Row2,3,4
Row3,5,6
Row4,7,8
Row5,9,10
"@

$data2 = @"
Table2,Column1
Row1,1
Row2,2
Row3,3
"@

$data3 = @"
Table3,Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5
Row1,1,2,3,4,5
Row2,6,7,8,9,10
"@


$html = @(
    "<html><body>"
    "This is table1"
    $data1 | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
    "This is table2"
    $data2 | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
    "This is table3"
    $data3 | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
    "</body></html>"
) | Out-String | Add-InlineStyle
```

Comment: Thank you, rokumaru, for your reply! Your solution works as well!

Comment: Nice solution! (+1)